# How to Choose to Send in a Parameter Based on a Condition?

Tags: rest-assured

I have an odd case where I have an optional attribute, but if I do send it in, it requires a value.

So normally I'd have something like

```
String valueForParam = "";
if(condition == true){
   valueForParam = "value";
}
given().request().param("parameter",valueForParam).when().put(URL)
```

But the problem is in my case if the parameter is sent in with a blank value (when condition is false) the service will throw an error.

I know I could make an if statement to call a completely different given() when the parameter is false, but I'm curious if there is a way to stop the parameter from being sent in when the value is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RequestSpecBuilder:

```
String valueForParam = "";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>;
if(condition == true){
   params.put("parameter", "value");
}
RequestSpecification s = new RequestSpecBuilder().addParams(params).build();
given().spec(s).when().put(URL);
```